# Angular automatically escaping HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

### The goal

The goal is to build a minimalistic wysiwyg editor in a text area. Retrieving a string from a network call, an interaction will add an `anchor` tag around selected text, and being able to send that (unescaped!) string over a network call.

The question is around Angular's built-in security measure to escape or ignore HTML tags.

### Expected result:

before: `Textarea value is set to this string`
after: `Textarea <a>value</a> is set to this string`

However, angular (11) is automatically escaping / ignoring the HTML.

I've found and tried several solutions that use the `[innerHTML]` directive rather than `[(ngModel)]` directive. But since I'm working with two-way data bindings, this did not cut it.

If anyone knows a way to nudge angular to ignore this html sanitization for a single input field, I look forward to read about it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DomSanitizer` (inject it) and do something like following:

```js
 this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how exactly are you planning on sanitizing the output (or for that matter, input), but have a look at https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml